# Check if a digit is a combination of only 2 digits

Tags: python, numbers

I have created a function which checks if the number has any other digit other than 3 or 5, return false.

```
def isDecent(n):
    digits = list(map(int, str(n)))
    for digit in digits:
        if digit != 3 or digit != 5: return False
    return True

print(isDecent(5553334))
```

But unfortunately it's not working! Can I know the problem?

Comment: Why is it not working? Do you get an error? Is it just the wrong result?

Comment: @isedev: in Python 3, `map` is a generator, and doesn't return a list. But your point still holds, as it's still possible to loop over a generator.

Comment: `return set(str(n)).issuperset('35')`

Comment: @SvenMarcnach: you mean subset.

Answer (score 6):

It's always true that `digit != 3` OR `digit != 5`. So it will always return False.

Change the `or` to `and`.

Alternatively, check it as

```
if digit not in (3, 5):
```

In fact, we don't need to convert the characters to ints just to check equality, and you could just do:

```
def isDecent(n):
    digits = str(n)
    return all(digit in ("3", "5") for digit in digits)
```

Or even `digit in "35"`... but I think that's less readable.

Another option is to use sets:

```
def isDecent(n):
    return set(str(n)).issubset('35')
```

Comment: And `return all(digit in '35' for digit in str(n))` would be a *decent* one-liner (har-har).

Comment: Your `issubset` test should use *string* digits, not integers, since the set contains the characters from `str(n)`. All you need is `set(str(n)).issubset('35')` as `.issubset()` will take any iterable.

Comment: Why is it always true even when the current digit is not 3 or 5?

Comment: Say you have a digit x. Either it is equal to 3, or it isn't. If it's equal to 3, then x != 5 is true. If it's not, then x != 3 is true. At least one of them is always true, so x != 3 or x != 5 is always true.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: If the digit is `3` then `digit != 5` is `True`.  And if the digit is `5` then `digit != 3 ` is `True`.  Since `or` evaluates to true as long as one if its tests is true, it will always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

Since the why part has been already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22251766/1903116), let me show you how to do this efficiently

```
def isDecent(n):
    return all(char in '35' for char in str(n))
```

The sister version of the same

```
def isDecent(n):
    return not any(char not in '35' for char in str(n))
```

Comment: doesn't that lack another `not`?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using an `or` instead of an `and`.

Just change your code to this :

```
def isDecent(n):
    digits = list(map(int, str(n)))
    for digit in digits:
        if digit != 3 and digit != 5: return False
    return True

print(isDecent(555333))
```

And then everything works !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoiding the conversion to a string:

```
def isDecent(n):
    if n == 0:
        return False

    while n: 
        if n % 10 not in (3, 5, ): 
            return False 
        n //= 10

    return True
```

Comment: But what about 0? (or negative numbers, but nobody considered those yet)

Comment: Added handling for `0`. If you want negative numbers just use `abs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set:

```
d=str(55555333)
r=''.join(set(d))
if r in '353':
    print "Number contains 3 or 5"
```

Comment: To fix your test change to `if r in '353':`  (not that I'm a fan of going from int to string to set to string).

Comment: Thanks if i edit as if r in '35', it should fix..right?

Comment: You already have a set, instead of changing it to a string and going through all the possibilities you can just check if it's a subset of {3, 5} with `set(d).issubset({3, 5})`.

Comment: Thanks...edited...I did not realize..i was testing for "555333" and "333555" as input r was coming always as "35"..thats how i missed it..

Answer (score 0):

Other's have shown the problem in your code, here's an alternative.

```
def isDecent(n):
     if not set(str(n)) - {'3','5','.'}:
             return False
     return True
```

It returns `False` on if str(n) contains anything other than `'3'` , `'5'` or `'.'`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def isDecent(n):
    s = set([ x for x in str(n)])
    if len(s) > 2:
        return False
    return [False,True]['3' in s and '5' in s]

for i in [5553334, 5553133, 111115, 33333555]:
    print i, isDecent(i)
```

Output:

```
5553334 False
5553133 False
111115 False
5553335 True
```

Comment: `'3' and '5' in s` doesn't do what you think it does, it means `('3') and ('5' in s)`, which is always true

Comment: could you please proved with one example.

Comment: Try with 14, or 3, etc.

Comment: typically, in your case, `111115` gives `True`